# Guess a function that fits empirical data

Tags: functions, regression

This is my empirical data:

[image]

Which function it looks like?

I tried to guess (1) a dumped (exponential decaying) sinusoidal, but it does not oscillate after overshoot; (2) a sigmoid, but it oscillate before rising and settled down as a negative exponential after the overshoot.

[This is the data in .csv format.](http://pastebin.com/qqG29iDM)

Comment: If I may ask, how many data points do you have ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici 250 points.

Comment: Is there any context in which this data came from?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 yes, but I don't think it impact in the response. VMs (y axis) refers to the amount of virtual machine that host a service after a step in the workload. E.g in a cloud computing environment.

Answer (score 1):

It looks similar to a Hill Equation in my opinion!  Refer to [this](http://parts.igem.org/wiki/images/4/4a/Pbadwt.png), which is plotted in context.